# Distance_Type_Earshot Runtime Error, Nearby Messages API

Tags: android, microphone, google-nearby, google-nearby-messages

How do I resolve a Runtime error by `Distance_Type_Earshot`?
I'm trying to build **Nearby Messages API** (just the audio/earshot) into my Android application, I've even built another demo app to test it out again, but same issue.

Basically, everything is set up okay, when using `Distance_Type_Default`, it works just fine too, but for some reason whenever it's set to `Distance_Type_Earshot` it just doesn't work. The funny thing is there are no exceptions or errors, it's just that the phones I'm testing with just can't seem to detect each other? I'm trying to use audio/microphone exclusively, as my app can't use BLE/Bluetooth.

I've tried changing **Discovery** to Broadcast and Scan and Default, it doesn't seem to make a difference but the issue still stands.

Answer (score 0):

The API stopped working for me with the latest Google Play Services release April 1, 2021.

I have asked for clarification specifically on the Earshot/ultrasonics only setting as my app had been working for over a year.  See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184423907  I may have filed the issue in the wrong place, also why I am here :-p

For the discovery, at least one device needs to *broadcast* the "anonymous token" code to one or more devices that are listening (*scan*).

If everyone is broadcasting and scanning, then the protocol needs a bit more time to chose a leader. If there is a single broadcaster and multiple scanners - there is no need to spend time to negotiate who is in charge.   (Faster)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Honestly you saved me a lot of hassle and worry because I only set it up after the Nearby Messages crash. I was wondering what was wrong and couldn't figure out why the audio just didn't seem to work.
Well I hope Google solves this quickly, but now I'm not sure if the API is even stable and reliable